# Pass controller variables to ng-class and ng-model inside templateUrl directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am attempting to create a custom element for a simple on-off switch using UI Bootstrap, here's an example:

```
<div class="btn-group" name="buttonName">
            <label ng-class="{'btn btn-default': !onOrOff, 'btn btn-primary': onOrOff}" ng-model="onOrOff" uib-btn-radio="true" uncheckable>Yes</label>
            <label ng-class="{'btn btn-default': onOrOff, 'btn btn-warning': !onOrOff}" ng-model="onOrOff" uib-btn-radio="false" uncheckable>No</label>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is to be able to keep track of the onOrOff state with ng-model and set that initial state via interpolation, but that doesn't seem to play nice with ng-class. Ideally I'd like to be able to utilize something like this in my code:

```
<onoff-switch name="buttonName" onOrOff="{{myController.initialValue}}"></onoff-switch>
```

How would I go about doing this? I am fairly new to angular so please forgive me if there are any obvious flaws in my approach.

Comment: Try removing the interpolation ({{}}) around your initial value?

Comment: it should be `on-or-off="{{myController.initialValue}}"`

Comment: Thank you, the combination of both of your suggestions helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try a directive for your example (only for example).

```
angular.module('yourAppNam', []).directive('onoffSwitch', function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            name: '=',
            onOrOff: '='
        },
        template: '<div class="btn-group" name="{{name}}">
            <label ng-class="{'btn btn-default': !onOrOff, 'btn btn-primary': onOrOff}" ng-model="onOrOff" uib-btn-radio="true" uncheckable>Yes</label>
            <label ng-class="{'btn btn-default': onOrOff, 'btn btn-warning': !onOrOff}" ng-model="onOrOff" uib-btn-radio="false" uncheckable>No</label>
</div>',
        restrict: 'E'
    };
})
```

Comment: Yes I have attempted to use a directive in this fashion, but how should I construct it? Right now neither of the variables are evaluating properly when the page is displayed, something to do with interpolation inside ng-class that requires a work around.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue, here is a solution that appears to be working:

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.directive('onoffSwitch', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            name: '=',
            onOrOff: '='
        },
        template: '<div class="btn-group" name="{{name}}"><label ng-class="{\'btn btn-default\': !onOrOff, \'btn btn-warning\': onOrOff }" ng-model="onOrOff" uib-btn-radio="true" uncheckable>Yes</label><label ng-class="{\'btn btn-default\': onOrOff, \'btn btn-primary\': !onOrOff }" ng-model="onOrOff" uib-btn-radio="false" uncheckable>No</label></div>',

    };
});
```

Element:

```
<onoff-switch name="buttonName" on-or-off="myController.initialValue"></onoff-switch>
```